# Youtube Player video not loading

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have a activity called **VideoActivity**.Below the **youtubeplayerview** there is a list of videos.On the first time the video is loading.When i click on a item then go to another activity and then return to that activity, it does not play. May i know the reason ?

Here is the code

```
public class VideoActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

public Video video;
private RecyclerView recyclerVideos;
private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

    recyclerVideos = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerVideos);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    video = (Video) i.getSerializableExtra("video");

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    recyclerVideos.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    new VideoAsyncTask().execute();

 }

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                    YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {

    if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
        errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
    } else {
        String errorMessage = String.format(
                getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
        Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                    YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo(video.Videoid);
        player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
        // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
        getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Constants.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }
}

private YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
}

private class VideoAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Video> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Video doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
         return   webservice();

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final Video video) {
        try {
            if (video == null) {
                return;
            }

            VideosAdapter videoAdapter = new VideosAdapter(video.videos,VideoActivity.this);
            recyclerVideos.setAdapter(videoAdapter);
    youTubeView.initialize(Constants.DEVELOPER_KEY, VideoActivity.this);

        } catch (Throwable ignored) {}
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.I solved the issue.

**Step 1** : add the youtubeview to linearlayout

**Step 2** : on **onResume** remove the view and add the youtubeview to linearlayout again when return to activity

**Step 3** : stop the youtube video in back press

Comment: Could you please add more detail on how you implement this. I tried your step but it still failed to work. Thank you.

Comment: @DucLe : Hey I created a LinearLayout in xml and added the youtubeview to LinearLayout and then initialized it.If i again come to this activity from another activity then in onResume I removed the view and add it again.

Comment: I can't make it work. Can you show some code please? I tried adding the YouTubePlayerView programmatically and also from xml. Video still don't load.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
super.onResume();
try {
        if (video == null) {
            return;
        }

       YouTubePlayer.loadVideo(String videoId, int timeMillis);

    } catch (Throwable ignored) {}
}
```

Comment: it comes onResume?? video == null??

Comment: Yes.It came.But didn't loaded the video

Comment: try once Instead of player.cuevideo(videoid) use player.loadVideo(videoId) in onInitializationSuccess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128263/discussion-between-debugger-and-sasikumar).

Answer (score 0):

try finishing the activity when you leave it , 
or initializing the youtubeplay on resume instead of oncreate

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    new VideoAsyncTask().execute();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before leaving activity/fragment where the YouTubePlayerView is do this:

```
youtubePlayer.pause();
youtubePlayer.release();
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of  my manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".UGNEWS24"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ugnews24_rounded_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/ugnews24_rounded_logo"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedDebugMode">
    <activity android:name=".activity.WebViewActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".SearchResultsActivity" />
```